# "Spresense メインボードへのイメージの書き込み"の動作開始が遅い

Tags: spresense

spresenseの [sdk開発のチュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3_hello_world_%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86)に沿って"Hellof, World"の実行を現在行おうとしています。
spresenseにイメージの書き込むを行うために、`tools/flash.sh -c /dev/ttyUSB0 nuttx.spk`を実行しました。次のように表示されますが、表示が開始するまでに数分以上かかります。これは通常通りの反応なのでしょうか？

```
>>> Install files ...
install -b 115200
Install nuttx.spk
|0%-----------------------------50%------------------------------100%|
######################################################################

159696 bytes loaded.
Package validation is OK.
Saving package to "nuttx"
updater# sync
updater# Restarting the board ...
reboot
```

なお、イメージの書き込みが終わったら正しくプログラムは動くことは確認できています。

使用している環境は以下の通りです。
・Windows11
・WSL20.04

Comment: 自分は数秒で書き込み開始しているので、数分かかるのは異常な気がします。環境の問題っぽいのでUSBドライバのバージョンを入れ直してみるとかで改善したりしないでしょうか
<https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_set_up_ja.html#_windows11wsl2向けセットアップ>
「4.シリアルドライバのインストール」参照